# Gradle Roboletric for different build type

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I am trying to get Roboletric working for my Android project. What I have right now is

```
task roboletricTest(type: Test, dependsOn: "assemble") {
testClassesDir = sourceSets.robolectricTest.output.classesDir

android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
    def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')
    buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build', 'intermediates', 'classes', 'debug']).join('/')
    sourceSets.robolectricTest.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
    sourceSets.robolectricTest.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
}

classpath = sourceSets.robolectricTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

The problem is that this task dependsOn: "assemble", so whenever I want to run the tests it would build all the different build types (ie debug and release). What I want is to be able to dynamically set the dependsOn variable depending on if the programmer wants assembleDebug or assembleRelease. I know I can create two different tasks to solve this, but I want a more elegant way of having one tasks that would work dynamically (because I have many build types).
Is there a way to dynamically check if a task will be executed?

Comment: What plugin do you use for running test? What Robolectric version?

Comment: Not using a plugin. Using version 2.2

Comment: Robolectric 2.3 is already released. You don't need custom tasks, better to use plugin. Check this https://github.com/emartynov/UrlSetter/blob/master/build.gradle